# C# ByteArray to string conversion and back

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a uint value that I need to represent as a ByteArray and the convert in a string.
When I convert back the string to a byte array I found different values.
I'm using standard ASCII converter so I don't understand why I'm getting different values.
To be more clear this is what I'm doing:

```
byte[] bArray = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)49694);
string test = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bArray);
byte[] result = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test);
```

The bytearray result is different from the first one:

bArray ->

```
[0x00000000]: 0x1e
[0x00000001]: 0xc2
[0x00000002]: 0x00
[0x00000003]: 0x00
```

result ->

```
[0x00000000]: 0x1e
[0x00000001]: 0x3f
[0x00000002]: 0x00
[0x00000003]: 0x00
```

Notice that the byte 1 is different in the two arrays.

Thanks for your support.

Regards

Comment: This was asked. did you do searching on SO?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
string test = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bArray);
byte[] result = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test);
```

Because raw data **is not ASCII**. `Encoding.GetString` is **only meaningful** if the data you are decoding *is text data in that encoding*. Anything else: you corrupt it. If you want to store a `byte[]` as a `string`, then base-n is necessary - typically base-64 because a: it is conveniently available (`Convert.{To|From}Base64String`), and b: you can fit it into ASCII, so you rarely hit code-page / encoding issues. For example:

```
byte[] bArray = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)49694);
string test = Convert.ToBase64String(bArray); // "HsIAAA=="
byte[] result = Convert.FromBase64String(test);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Because c2 is not a valid ASCII char and it is replaced with '?'(3f)
```

Converting any byte array to string using `SomeEncoding.GetString()` is not a safe method as [@activwerx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033686/activwerx) suggested in comments. Instead use `Convert.FromBase64String`, `Convert.ToBase64String`

Comment: Thanks for you answer. C1 is a valid char in extended ASCII. Is there a way to manage that situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @lordpurple, if the values are not standard ASCII, you may want to use a different encoding, such as Encoding.UTF8 etc.

Comment: @lordpurple Converting *any* byte array to string using SomeEncoding.GetString() is not a safe method. Instead use `Convert.FromBase64String`, `Convert.ToBase64String`