# C# equivalent of Python's struct.pack?

Tags: c#, python, struct, pack, unpack

Is there any function equivalent to Python's struct.pack and struck.unpack in C# that allows me to pack and unpack values like this?

```
def hexlongbits2double(str):
    return struct.unpack('d', struct.pack('Q', int(str, 16)))[0]
```

Comment: this question looks like it may have an answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344041/c-sharp-bytearray-to-string-conversion-and-back

Comment: I don't know Python, but a quick Google search says that `struct.pack` takes some value(s) and turns them into a string with the given format.  And that `struct.unpack` takes a string and tries to convert that string into a C struct specified by the given format.  And your example here takes some string `str` (that in theory is a hex string) converts that into an int from base 16, packs that into a 64bit integer string, then unpacks that into a double precision floating point number.  Do I have it right so far?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your goal.
If it is conversion from hex to double, you can use following C# methods:
[How to: Convert Between Hexadecimal Strings and Numeric Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)

If what you need is serialization/deserialization, for example for networking, you can find good information [here](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/8n/Serialization-in-C.html).